# Currency field missing on Coinbase Pro API transfers endpoint

Tags: coinbase-api

I'm using the [List Deposits endpoint](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/?r=1#deposits) of the Coinbase Pro API, but the data returned on the response gives me no clue as to what kind of currency (fiat or crypto) was used for it:

```
  {
    id: 'xxx',
    type: 'deposit',
    created_at: '2017-11-27 09:03:13.278111+00',
    completed_at: '2017-11-27 09:03:14.112826+00',
    canceled_at: null,
    processed_at: '2017-11-27 09:03:14.112826+00',
    account_id: 'xxx',
    user_id: 'xxx',
    user_nonce: null,
    amount: '2001.00000000',
    details: {
      coinbase_account_id: 'xxx',
      coinbase_transaction_id: 'xxx'
    },
    idem: null
  }
```

I've tried using the id with the Single Deposit endpoint but I get the same result. I know the currency can be gotten somehow, because there's plenty of portfolio tracking services doing it, so I must be doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it can be. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it :) This requires a first request to the [Accounts endpoint](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#accounts), which returns `currency` and `id`, and that `id` needs to be matched with the `account_id` field of the deposit.